# How do I select property inside multiple divs

Tags: html, css

I have this:

```
<div id="sidebar-a">
   <form id="form">
      <input class="button" type="submit">
      </input>
   </form>
</div>
```

And I need to select only the ***input*** (my page has same `<form>` in `#footer`, the only way to change property of this one is, like I tried to do, with `#sidebar-a`, but it doesn't work)

Comment: Estudo (ou melhor, vou começar a estudar) e também trabalho @letiagoalves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you made no mention of JQuery, I'm assuming you're trying to select the input element via CSS.

```
#sidebar-a > form > input.button:first-child {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

An example is [available at this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KthgS/)

Answer (score 2):

You should not have 2 `form` elements with same ID. However this will do it:

```
#sidebar-a > form > input.button:first-of-type { }
```

Comment: That's correct. In fact, the best way to say that is "You should not have same ID twice in the same page". :) My ID is rendering like this: #form579 (`#form` + ID of the `form`), so that will not affect HTML basic rules...